# Calculate $\int_{\substack{x_1\geq 0,\ldots, x_n \geq 0\\ x_1+\cdots+x_n \leq 2}}\sqrt[n]{x_1\cdots x_n\left(x_1+\cdots+x_n\right)} dx_1\cdots d x_n$

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

Calculate:  $$I = \int_{\substack{x_1 \geq 0, \ldots, x_n \geq 0 \\   x_1+\cdots+x_n \leq 2}} \sqrt[n]{x_1 \cdots x_n\left(x_1+\cdots+x_n\right)}\, d x_1 \cdots d x_n$$

Attempt: Perform the substitution $ x_i = 2y_i $, the Jacobian will be $ 2^n $ and so $$I=2^{n+1+\frac{1}{n}} \cdot \int_{\substack{x_1 \geq 0, \ldots, x_n \geq 0 \\   x_1+\cdots+x_n \leq 1}} \prod x_i^{\frac{1}{n}} \cdot \sqrt[n]{\left(\sum_j x_j\right)}\,dx_i$$

I don't know how to continue, any ideas?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: where did you get this question from ?

Comment: Old exam question which didn't have any answer. The set $\begin{aligned} & x_1 \geq 0, \ldots, x_n \geq 0 \\ & x_1+\cdots+x_n \leq 1\end{aligned}$ corresponds to an n-th dimensional simplex, I also thought about gamma function here ( perhaps some substitution will be able to convert the integral to a gamma function ) but I dont know.

Comment: Well, I happy that I am not one of the student who took this exam, btw what kind of exam that have this kind of hard questions ?

Comment: I am curious what university have these kind of exams ? Did anyone solve it ?

Comment: Well, you were right, I managed to get a different sheet of the exam and it said to use the formula ( called " extended Dirichlet equation" ) : $\int_{\substack{x_1 \ldots, x_n \geq 0 \\ x_1+\ldots+x_n \leq 1}} f\left(x_1+\ldots+x_n\right) x_1^{p_1-1} \ldots x_n^{p_n-1} d x_1 \ldots d x_n=\frac{\Gamma\left(p_1\right) \ldots \Gamma\left(p_n\right)}{\Gamma\left(p_1+\ldots+p_n\right)} \int_0^1 f(t) t^{p_1+\ldots+p_n-1} d t$ , I think I can continue from here, thanks!